# Stacking windows 10 toast notifications in tray

Tags: c#, windows-10, toast

i'm trying to find how to change tast notifications in my application so it will stack when i show a few in a row. Sometimes it is possible to show 3-5 in a row, but it is popping one after another and not at once as in ms Teams for example or lastly i found that slack has the same.

example:
[image]

And he is my code how i show notifications:

```
        var toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);
        string toastModel = Serialization.Serialize(notification, withTypeHandling: true);
        toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text")[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(toastContent));
        (toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("toast")[0] as Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement).SetAttribute("launch", toastModel);
        DesktopNotificationManagerCompat.CreateToastNotifier().Show(new ToastNotification(toastXml));
```

Was trying to change something in appending childs but it only ended at no working at all.
Anyone has solution for that problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Windows does not provide a way to stack notifications. The stacking notifications you are seeing in Microsoft Teams is a seperate system from the Windows notifications. In the NEW Microsoft Teams they have dropped their own notification system in favour of Windows notifications so there is no longer stacking in Teams either.